# JS with syntax error

Tags: javascript, function, syntax-error

```
self.sortDeadlineFwdLive = function () {
self.deadline_fwd_lives.sort(function (left, right) {
    if (left.penalty_due_date() || right.penalty_due_date()) {
        if (left.penalty_due_date() == right.penalty_due_date()) {
            return left.returned_date() == right.returned_date() ? 0 : ((left.returned_date() && left.returned_date() < right.returned_date()) || !right.returned_date() ? -1 : 1);
        }
        return left.fl_due_date() == right.fl_due_date() ? 0 : ((left.fl_due_date() && left.fl_due_date() < right.fl_due_date()) || !right.fl_due_date() ? -1 : 1);
    }
    return left.penalty_due_date() == right.penalty_due_date() ? 0 : ((left.penalty_due_date() && left.penalty_due_date() < right.penalty_due_date()) || !right.penalty_due_date() ? -1 : 1);
} else if (left.fl_due_date() == right.fl_due_date()) {
    if (left.penalty_due_date() != right.penalty_due_date()) {
        return left.returned_date() == right.returned_date() ? 0 : ((left.returned_date() && left.returned_date() < right.returned_date()) || !right.returned_date() ? -1 : 1);
    }
    return left.fl_due_date() == right.fl_due_date() ? 0 : ((left.fl_due_date() && left.fl_due_date() < right.fl_due_date()) || !right.fl_due_date() ? -1 : 1);
} else {
    return left.returned_date() == right.returned_date() ? 0 : ((left.returned_date() && left.returned_date() < right.returned_date()) || !right.returned_date() ? -1 : 1);

}
});
};
```

Above is the code for my js function, however i cant get it right, been trying for hours, still can't figure out, im terrible with js, any kind soul can solve it, maybe just syntax error

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/08o67mmm/)**

Comment: Have you tried systematically eliminating and re-introducing code until you find the problematic line?

Comment: As far as I know, all of the major browsers have developer tools. Press the <F12> key and something should pop up. Select the "Console" tab, run the JavaScript, and errors will be displayed in the console.

Comment: The console shows `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else `. [Learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging), Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the starting `if` clause right before `if (left.penalty_due_date() || right.penalty_due_date()) {`.

Comment: i dont get it, i don't think that is the problem, can you provide the jsfiddle to it to prove it is correct? @limelights

Comment: @CheongDMunPong provided: http://jsbin.com/rokixucasu/1/edit?js

Comment: Why do i still see so many errors for that you provided? can you fix the errors and show me again? i can check the difference myself, tq much

Comment: I provided you with a jsbin that shows your exact problem.

Comment: You mean the errors or the comment you added? I don't really understand your comment, appreciate much if you can fix the code, so i can see the difference

Comment: You have to fix it yourself. I've pointed out where and why it's breaking...

Comment: Anyway, that is the exact reason why i am posting this question, I used jsfiddle as you can see in the question, i know which lines are having problems, yet i dont know how to fix it

Comment: You are missing an if clause at the beginning of your function.

Comment: ok, i will try from here onwards, tq

Answer (score 3):

The error is on this line:

```
} else if (left.fl_due_date() == right.fl_due_date()) {
```

The `}` is closing a function, not an if.

Comment: i dont get it, i don't think that is the problem, can you provide the jsfiddle to it to prove it is correct?

Comment: @CheongDMunPong: Look at the indentation of your code. Don't you find it odd that the `else if` block doesn't line up with an `if` block?